# How to use powershell/bash script file in azure pipeline template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

example: Azure Devops, I have one organization, few projects, and few repositories inside each project (most of them contains build pipelines):

ORGANIZATION:
..-- Project1
.....-- Repo1
.....-- Repo2
..-- Project2
.....-- Repo1
.....-- Repo2
..-- BuildTemplates
.....-- BuildTemplatesRepository
........-- Template1.yml
........-- Template2.yml
........-- Template1.ps1

Template1.yml contains powershell task or step:
- pwsh: ./Template1.ps1

Problem:
When Template1.yml executes inside pipelines from another repo (Project1/Repo1/azure-pipelines.yml) I get error:
[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Template1.ps1'

I understand why there is error, because *.ps1 file isn't copied inside container where process is going on, but how to solve this issue in best way (without coping this script manually)?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue , you can check out multiple repositories in your pipeline.

Pipelines often rely on multiple repositories. You can have different repositories with source, tools, scripts, or other items that you need to build your code. By using multiple `checkout` steps in your pipeline, you can fetch and check out other repositories in addition to the one you use to store your YAML pipeline.

So you can check out other repo that contains `Template1.ps1` in the pipeline .

```
steps:
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
```

For details ,please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-declared-using-inline-syntax).